# Where is the PreloadingStrategy in @angular/router ver 3.1.0

Tags: angular

I've just installed the version 3.1.0 of the angular2 router with npm; but I don't see the `PreloadingStrategy` nor the  `@angular/router/src/router_preloader.ts` file. According to this blog post: http://angularjs.blogspot.ro/2016/10/angular-210-now-available.html it should be available. Am I missing something or could there be a problem with the npm package?

My full list of dependencies in the package.json is bellow:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  }
```

Comment: Well, [it's there](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.1.0/modules/%40angular/router/src/index.ts#L18). Do you have problems with `import { PreloadingStrategy } from '@angular/router'`? There shouldn't be `@angular/router/src/router_preloader.ts` because NPM package contains transpiled files, and if you import router_preloader.ts from package internals, you do it the wrong way.

Comment: @estus you are right, it was just a problem with my IDE that hasn't indexed the npm module after the update and said that it can't find the `PreloadingStrategy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in "@angular/router": "3.1.2",

```
export declare abstract class PreloadingStrategy {
    abstract preload(route: Route, fn: () => Observable<any>): Observable<any>; }

export declare class PreloadAllModules implements PreloadingStrategy {
    preload(route: Route, fn: () => Observable<any>): Observable<any>; }
```